# Unable to specify custom path for pdf.worker.js in PDFjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf.js

I have implemented PDFjs in my ASP.NET MVC application. The steps which I have followed.

- Created an action that works as Pdf Viewer by copying the code provided by PDFjs as `WebViewer.html`.
- On this page, I properly provided paths to all the static resources that are required by this HTML page.

Now the only problem is the path of `pdf.worker.js`. When I run the application, I get an error that this file not found. Even after lots of efforts, I am not able to fix this issue. Can anybody tell me that where I need to make a change in the code so that I can specify a custom path to this file?

[image]

As per code, I can say that this js file is internally referenced by `pdf.js`. But `pdf.js` file seems to be generated by WebPack and updating `pdf.worker.js` path in this file not affecting anything.

This is how pdf.js code looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the PDF.js default viewer, the application options are in the **viewer.js** file. While  I don't have a complete understanding of exactly how it works, it seems the viewer layer passes configuration values to the pdf.js display layer as necessary.

In version 2.0+, you can change the hard-coded value for `workerSrc`, which looks like this by default:

```
workerSrc: {
  value: '../build/pdf.worker.js',
  kind: OptionKind.WORKER
}
```

I couldn't figure out a way to dynamically set this in 2.0.

In the newly pre-released 2.1, thanks to [this pull request](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/10318), you can use the custom `webviewerloaded` event to more easily set viewer options. For example,

```
document.addEventListener('webviewerloaded', function () {
    document.PDFViewerApplicationOptions.set('workerSrc', '/your/path/here/pdf.worker.js');
});
```

Comment: By coincidence, I also started implementing PDF.js into ASP.NET MVC about a month ago.